# PHP passing parameters to a function

Tags: php

I want to pass a parameter to a function as below for clarity. It doesn't give any error. But is this a bad practice. Do I have to avoid this.

```
test('','','',$d='text','');

function test($a, $b, $c, $d, $e){

}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the practice of passing parameters to functions, or are you asking about the particular syntax that you used in your function call?

Comment: Just want to know whether above syntax is correct and don't make any harm to my program.

Comment: As it is a question about specific syntax, it belongs on StackOverflow. I have already marked the question for migration, so there is nothing you need to do to get it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually find this question interesting :)

My take is that this is a bad practice today in PHP. That kind of syntax is typical of Python which has a feature called "named parameters" that allows calling a function without using the same order of variable calls.

There is an RFC in the php community to add this syntax to the language:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params

The internal discussion about this feature is not finished yet, personally I would like to have this feature.

As of today (PHP 5.5), you get no benefit at all in using this syntax as you are just evaluating the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to assign the $str variable inline like that? Does it improve clarity at all?

I believe it's just evaluating `$str = 'test'` and passing the result `$str` to the function call.

`$str` remains assigned in the current scope so you could continue to use $str after the `test()` call if you wanted to.

It's the same as

```
$str = 'test';
test($str);
```

It's a bit weird looking and may be misleading when reading the code later so I would avoid doing that.

Comment: Actually I never pass parameters to function like this before. But Today I get an requirement to pass a parameter like this. I just worried about whether this is a unrecomanded code. Thank you for clarification.